# Struct legal value constraints configuration inheritance

Tags: c, inheritance, configuration, struct, tcl

In order to maintain and test a large set of structs with various constraints on what are legal values for their many fields, we are building a generic system of additional structs that will describe the range of legal values for each of these items. The challenge is in preventing as much code duplication as humanly possible and I think that an inheritence-like mechanism where specific cases could inherit from more generic parent cases.

For instance, lets say we have a generic `car` `struct` and that the legal values are(pseudo code):

```
struct car-constraints {
    max-speed-range [80  - 220] //unit is in MPH
    total-weight    [0.5 - 4.0] //unit is in tons
    door-count      [2.0 - 6.0] //unit is integer
}
```

Now imagine the above only that the struct actually contains dozens of fields and the actually describes a configuration of some specific networking functionality. Now we have a very similar struct and we simply want to modify one of the constraints(for instance):

```
struct sports-car-constraints (inherits) car-constraints{
    max-speed-range [150  - 370] //unit is in MPH -> The original value is overriden
}
```

Any ideas how I could implement this in C so I could easily set and get a struct with correct range of legal values for each object in the system?

The reasons I would need the constraints in the code:

1. It would allow us to randomly create an instance with legal or faulty field values for testing purposes.
2. It would encourage developers to write self-documenting code describing the legal range of values.
3. It would prevent a large amount of code duplication.

The main challenge I am facing is that c does not natively support inheritance. We are using tcl for scripting which is a very flexible but I don't see how I would go about writing generic code that will fire up tcl and get back a struct with the correct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider writing a code-generator. An outline of this approach is as follows:

1. Using whatever happens to be your favourite configuration-file syntax (and library for parsing that syntax), write a configuration file that acts as a specification of what you want to have in your C structs.
2. Write an code-generation utility that parses that configuration file and uses print statements to generate a pair of `.h` and `.c` files that defines the C structs plus whatever supporting functions are required to get/set their fields and do range checks.
3. Your `Makefile` should run the code-generation utility, and then compile the generated code, along with the hand-written code of your project.

The code-generation application does not have to be implemented in C. Instead, you can write it in whatever language you feel is best suited for the task. For example, since you are using Tcl in your project, you could use Tcl for both items 1 and 2 in the above list.

Comment: This is the solution we'll be going with. Writing an auto code-generator in Tcl. I could easily implement the desired inheritance behavior in Tcl and let it generate the c code for getting struct samples and defining the struct instances that will contain the relevant constraints.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't have inheritance as you are describing in your question.

I can think of a preprocessor trick that minimizes the amount of code to write if you are only adding new fields (not overwriting fields) in a base structure:

```
#define BASE_CAR_CONSTRAINTS \
   max_speed_range ...       \
   total_weight ...          \
   door_count ...            
   .
   .
   .

struct car_constraints {
   BASE_CAR_CONSTRAINTS
};

struct sports_car_constraints {
   BASE_CAR_CONSTRAINTS
   wheel_diameter_range ...
   .
   .
};
```

For your immediate need of overwriting a field in a 'base class' (base struct), why not just use the above method, create an instance of a `sports_car_constraints` and just overwrite the field `max_speed_range`?

This way you are:

- not copying the entire structure all over again
- only incrementally modifying in the 'derived struct' the deltas from the 'base struct'

Answer (score 0):

One of the main ways to do something like this is to include the parent structure as the first member value of the child structure:

```
struct car-constraints {
    max-speed-range [80  - 220] //unit is in MPH
    total-weight    [0.5 - 4.0] //unit is in tons
    door-count      [2.0 - 6.0] //unit is integer
}

struct sports-car-constraints {
    struct car-constraints parent;
    max-speed-range [150  - 370] //unit is in MPH -> The original value is overriden
}
```

That then lets you safely cast a `sports-car-constraints *` to a `car-constraints *` (**NB:** pointers to structures!) and reuse the existing constraint-management code.

However, you probably ought to put a field in the real `car-constraints` that holds a pointer to a function that implements the real constraints checker, so that you can delegate knowledge of how to check constraints to code that will do the right thing whichever type it has. Then only the factory function has to understand everything; the clients of the code (including the Tcl interface) can ignore the complexity. (If there are several such functions, factor them out into their own structure; might as well reimplement vtables correctly at that point…)